# What's an efficient way to compare phone contacts to MySQL database? (Similar to WhatsApp)

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I am trying to determine which contacts from a user's phone are using my app, similar to what WhatsApp does. I have the list of contacts in a Cursor and am trying to figure out an efficient way to compare the list of contacts to my database to see who is using the app. I could do it like this:

```
//for each contact
while (this.cursor.moveToNext()) 
    {
        String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(2);
        String sanitizedPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\D", "");

        //query db to see if user exists
        boolean userExists = restClient.checkIfUserExists(sanitizedPhoneNumber);

        //save all results in hashmap
        //"phoneNumber":"exists"
        //"5556781234":"true"

    }
```

Doing it like this, there could potentially be hundreds of API calls to my web service in a row depending how many contacts there are, which is why I'm looking for an alternative. Is there a better way? Should I be using SyncAdapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you could first build a list of phone numbers on the device, and then make a single API call to an endpoint that takes in this list. Have the endpoint then respond back with a list of known numbers. This way, you're making only one HTTP request.

Comment: Yea that is the other solution I've thought about, which makes more sense than what I posted